Spring securitu redirect ti login page
I have a Spring boot application on Java 21 and Spring boot vesion 3.2.3
I want to protect the methods of a specific controller using basic authentication, but after adding the Spring Security configuration to the project, when I try to access Swagger or any other endpoint of the application, I get redirected to the login page, such as localhost:8443/myapp/login#/. What should I do? Here is the Spring Security configuration:
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicAuthFilter {

    @Value("${spring.security.user.name}")
    String basicAuthUser;

    @Value("${spring.security.user.password}")
    String basicAuthPassword;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(basicAuthUser)
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(basicAuthPassword))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request->request
                        .requestMatchers("/apidata**").authenticated())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request->request.requestMatchers("/**").permitAll())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();

}
}

in build.gradle
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.3.0'
I tried using the formLogin() construction as shown here  text, but it doesn't help.
